# SQL query runs from IDE but not in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, phpstorm

I've got this SQL code:

```
CREATE EVENT `update_statistics`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-08-24 02:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN

  UPDATE statistics
  SET km_traveled     = (SELECT sum(km)
                         FROM archived_trips),
    passengers_driven = (SELECT sum(passengers)
                         FROM archived_trips),
    trips_taken       = (SELECT count(*)
                         FROM archived_trips)
  WHERE id = 1;

  UPDATE statistics
  SET co_saved = ((SELECT km_traveled
                   FROM statistics) * 0.215 * (SELECT passengers_driven
                                               FROM statistics))
  WHERE id = 1;

END;
```

When I run it through the SQL console in PhpStorm - it runs fine and the scheduled task works and so on.

But if I try to run the query directly in phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13
```

Line 13 is `WHERE id=1;`. Honestly, I don't see any syntax problem with the query. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should wrap it with `DELIMITER //` and `// DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delimiter of the query is ';' and ';' is also used in the stored procedure, causing the query to fail.

Add `DELIMITER //` before the statement and end with `//` to fix this.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT `update_statistics`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-08-24 02:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN

  UPDATE statistics
  SET km_traveled     = (SELECT sum(km)
                         FROM archived_trips),
    passengers_driven = (SELECT sum(passengers)
                         FROM archived_trips),
    trips_taken       = (SELECT count(*)
                         FROM archived_trips)
  WHERE id = 1;

  UPDATE statistics
  SET co_saved = ((SELECT km_traveled
                   FROM statistics) * 0.215 * (SELECT passengers_driven
                                               FROM statistics))
  WHERE id = 1;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

With PHPstorm, sending multiple queries in one go is probably disabled, causing MySQL to ignore the delimiter.

Comment: I ran your solution in phpmyadmin and got this: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 21`. This is the line with `where id=1;` again.

Comment: I fixed it. At the end, just wrote: `END; // DELIMITER ;`. If you want - fix your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Milkncookiez Thanks for the feedback. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the DELIMITER to other char. else they cant find out the end of the EVENT.

```
DELIMITER //


CREATE EVENT `update_statistics`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-08-24 02:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN

  UPDATE statistics
  SET km_traveled     = (SELECT sum(km)
                         FROM archived_trips),
    passengers_driven = (SELECT sum(passengers)
                         FROM archived_trips),
    trips_taken       = (SELECT count(*)
                         FROM archived_trips)
  WHERE id = 1;

  UPDATE statistics
  SET co_saved = ((SELECT km_traveled
                   FROM statistics) * 0.215 * (SELECT passengers_driven
                                               FROM statistics))
  WHERE id = 1;

END//
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but try removing the semicolon after END.

Comment: This answer might be better suited as a comment to the original question.